# Yii2 custom gii generator and template?

Tags: yii2, gii

I just implementing a new gii generator for my requirement on yii2.
i want to know best place to keep those codes?

Comment: See official guide - [Creating your own templates](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/docs/guide/topics-creating-your-own-templates.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `app\modules\gii` directory with own Generator class, views, templates.

```
namespace app\modules\gii;

class MyCustomGenerator extends \yii\gii\generators\crud\Generator
{
    // ...

    public function generate()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then enable it in `gii` configuration.

```
[
    // ...
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => [
            'class'      => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'generators' => [
                'class' => '\app\modules\gii\MyCustomGenerator',
                'model' => ['class' => '\app\modules\gii\model\MyCustomGenerator'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: i know how to write, what i want is were to place the generator and template.

Comment: @VijayArun Place them in `app\modules\gii`, as I told in my anwer.

Answer (score 3):

Which module of gii that you need to custom? 
If it is CRUD module, I think you should put it into app/backend/ because it just use for this app.

Here is my customization: [custom crud gii templates](http://namdt5.blogspot.com/2017/06/yii2-gii-generators-how-to-custom-crud-gii-templates.html)

My folder structure: [yii2 - custom gii crud templates - folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhsxi.png)

Answer (score 1):

No good idea own gii template put in app/modules/gii. Better is create separate module. Benefits:

- can reuse in other projects
- if put it in composer under require_dev, do not install on production